# How do I bookmark all not bookmarked open tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Let's say you have Chrome opened with a window containing tabs that are already in bookmarks and some others that are not.

How can I put in bookmarks only the tabs that are not already boookmarked ?

Comment: if you are looking for native 1-click-solution, then there isnt any. star them or try: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/supersorter/hjebfgojnlefhdgmomncgjglmdckngij?hl=en

Comment: Well in Chromium you can do **`Ctrl`** + **`Shift`** + **`D`** . Not Sure If that works in chrome too.